# How to resolve SQL Server connection error

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have got an error like this

> "An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in
>   System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: A network-related or instance-specific error
>   occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was
>   not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is
>   correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.
>   (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a
>   connection to SQL Server)"

How to resolve it

Comment: check that you can connect to the database. post code. post the connection string you are using. how is the database being hosted?

Comment: Check if your SQL services are running.

Comment: Your connection string is probably wrong, or your have firewall issues.

Comment: https://db.tt/nhHHNjBN     ---> web config

Comment: I just install Windows 10